# R: Function within a function: managing environments

Tags: r

Within Function A, I have function B that takes 4 objects from the environment of function A and modifies them. Then, I need those objects to be sent back to the environment of function A.

I am looking for best practice recommendation:
Currently what I do is: Function B returns a list containing the object and each object is overwritten in the environment of function A. Is there a better way of handling this?
The discussions on managing environments are quite complex and this is an important and simple question for the community.

## Below is some pseudo code of my implementation

```
Function A = getObjects(A,B,C){

A= A+1
B= B+1
C= C+1

# Function B returns a list containing the object after certain operations were # performed on these

listFromFunctionB =  FunctionB(A,B,C)

A = listFromFunctionB$A
B = listFromFunctionB$B
C = listFromFunctionB$C

#Other operations keep going on objects A,B and C
}
```

Comment: If these objects always go together it might make more sense to keep them in a list - maybe even create an S3 class for the three of them together.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: I've added an answer. I don't think I can be more specific than that before you get more specific about the types of things you're doing. But the tl;dr is *keep them in a list and use `lapply`* rather taking them out of a list and putting them back in at every step.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is no better practice than what you have already got.

Functional programming languages (such as R) don't usually allow functions to modify input parameters.

Furthermore, an R function returns only one object, so your returning of the list containing objects A, B, and C is also the correct method.

Comment: What about setting those 2 functions in the same environment? 
I read its not recommended in most instances, but in the above would avoid to deal with the list and the outputs

Comment: As @tony says, passing lists is definitely the recommended way. It is not the only way. It is possible to change values in the parent scope from within a function using either <<- or assign(), but this would typically be bad practice and liable to cause unintended side effects. I *strongly* suggest you accept the advice you have in this answer and stick with using lists to return multiple values from a function as very much the best way. To quote from the R inferno.  "If you think you need <<- , think again. If on reﬂection you still think you need <<-, think again."

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your toy example, but it seems like you have 3 objects, A, B, and C, that are all operated on together and passed around together. At every step of the way, you take them out of a list, do something to each of them, and put them back in a list so that they can be returned as one from a function.

Generally, this is good. You can't return more than one object, so you need to return them in a list. The waste comes in taking them out of a list each time. Why bother?

In fact, doing the same thing to each item of a list is quite easy with `lapply`. Your code makes it look like you are copy/pasting lines and changing `A` to `B`, then to `C`. Good programming should involve very little copy/paste.

Rather than writing functions of `A, B, C`, write functions that expect `list(A, B, C)` as input.

The only example you have of *doing something* is adding one to A, B and C. Here is how you would do that if they were in a list:

```
FunctionA = function(ABClist) {
    # add 1 to each list element
    return(lapply(ABClist, function(x) x + 1))
}
```